# How to insert values into database when input names are like- name="fieldname[]?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following form, I have to insert the form values into database. But I don't how to insert these values when the field names are like - name="fieldname[]". For better understanding please check the following.

I am using Codeigniter. I have Views, controller and model, I have tried the usual way of inserting value but its not working.

One of my friends suggested me to use something like- mysql_real_escape_string($value) but I don't know how to use it. Would you please kindly help me?

Thanks in Advance :)

```
   <table> 
     <form >

   <tr>

      <td> Student ID: <input type="text" name="studentid[]" value="" /> </td>
      <td> Grade <input type="text" name="grade[]" value="" /></td>
      <td>Obtained Mark  <input type="text" name="obtainedmark[]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

     <td> Student ID: <input type="text" name="studentid[]" value="" /> </td>
     <td> Grade <input type="text" name="grade[]" value="" /></td>
     <td>Obtained Mark  <input type="text" name="obtainedmark[]" value="" /></td>

    </tr>


  <tr>
     <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" /></td>
 </tr>

 </form>
 </table>
```

## Edit

```
    foreach($_POST['studentid'] as $studentid) {
      // do something

    $data = array(              
    'subjectname' =>"",
    'subjectname' => $studentid             

    );                  
    $results=$this->db->insert('subject', $data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this works is you are getting an array of values for each field that has that name.  You say there are two of these

```
   <td> Student ID: <input type="text" name="studentid[]" value="" /> </td>
```

and when you do

```
 foreach($_POST['studentid'] as $studentid) {

  $data = array(              
  'subjectid' =>"",
  'subjectname' => $studentid             

   );                  
 $results=$this->db->insert('subject', $data);
```

you input two student ids.  You need to do it again your other inputs.  But wait?  How will you construct your sql query without the student names?  I would probably do something like

```
$studentids = addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['studentid']));
$subjectnames = addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['subjectnames']));
$obtainedmarks = addslashes(htmlentities($_POST['obtainedmarks']));

for($i = 0; $i < count($studentids); $i++){
 $data = array(              
  'subjectid' =>$studentids[$i],
  'subjectname' => $subjectnames[$i],             
'obtainedmarks' => $obtainedmarks[$i] 
   );                  
 $results=$this->db->insert('subject', $data);
}
```

Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you very very much Jakx. You script is working perfectly though I had to remove the addlashes and htmlentities thing to get it to work. With addlashes and htmlentities I was getting this error message- Severity: Warning

Message: htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. I replaced it with ($_POST['studentid']) and it is working just the way I wanted. Thank you very very much again. You have helped me a lot . :)

Answer (score 1):

These are Arrays, you can access them by the following code (example):

```
foreach($_POST['studentid'] as $studentid) {
  // do something
}
```

for your edit. this is just en example, idk whether this works or not. Just try around with it.

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$data) {
    foreach($data as $field) {
        $arr[$key][] = $field;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have checked your script and it is working fine but what would I do for the other two variables. .. grade and obtained mark. Please check the edited portion of my post above to see what I have developed so far.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php